# Is there a way to look up the OAuth2 provider ID from a ClientRegistration object?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am developing an application that uses Spring Security 5.x's OAuth2 support for login. One of my use cases requires having multiple client registrations for the same OAuth2 identity provider, and then looking up the provider ID at runtime given the `ClientRegistration` object corresponding to the in-scope OAuth2 client. Is there a public API that provides this information?

The `ClientRegistration` API: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/registration/ClientRegistration.html does not expose this information.

I had hoped that `ProviderDetails`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/registration/ClientRegistration.ProviderDetails.html would include it, but no luck there.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.x with YAML configuration. The value of the `provider` key in the client registration data is *exactly* what I need to access at runtime:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      provider:
        myprovider:
          authorization-uri: "https://oauth2.example.com/authorize"
          jwk-set-uri: "https://oauth2.example.com/jwks.json"
          token-uri: "https://oauth2.example.com/tokens"
      registration:
        client1:
          provider: "myprovider"
          client-id: "id-1"
          client-secret: "secret-1"
          authorization-grant-type: "authorization_code"
        client2:
          provider: "myprovider"
          client-id: "id-2"
          client-secret: "secret-2"
          authorization-grant-type: "authorization_code"
```

This seems like an odd oversight (and obviously it is available to Spring Security internally), so I am left scratching my head and wondering if I am missing something obvious.

I assumed I would be able to write something like this:

```
ClientRegistration registration = someObject.getClientRegistration();
String providerId = registration.getProviderId();
```

But I can't find anything equivalent to `#getProviderId()` above, or even a `ProviderRepository` analogous to the `ClientRegistrationRepository` bean.

Comment: Hi summerpils, I'm writing a Spring Filter to authenticate users when there is no active session and an id_token is present on the request. The OIDC client is registered (google) but I can't find a way to get the clientRegistration object in the `OncePerRequestFilter` context. I've tried setting the annotation @Autowired to a `ClientRegistrationRepository` variable but I got a null. Have you find a way to do that ?

Comment: Don't worry about this. The filter was configured twice and that was the error. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you take a look at the Spring Boot autoconfiguration, you'll see that this information is not saved in any way.

### **Explanation**

Take a look at `OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter` for the logic behind creating a `ClientRegistration`.

1. The provider `String` for each registration is captured in a field of  a `OAuth2ClientProperties.Registration` object that has been populated using your configuration.
2. The provider information you provide in `spring.security.oauth2.provider` is used to create a `OAuth2ClientProperties.Provider`. However, the "providerId" is not saved in the object itself (it has no "providerId" or "providerName" field anyway). Instead, the provider name/id is the key to a `Map<String,Provider>` that exists in `OAuth2ClientProperties`.
3. When building your `ClientRegistration`, the provider `String` in your `OAuth2ClientProperties.Registration` is used to search the map. Once the provider is found, it is used to configure the `ClientRegistration.Builder`.

This is all that's obtained from the `OAuth2ClientProperties.Provider`:

```
private static Builder getBuilder(Builder builder, Provider provider) {
    PropertyMapper map = PropertyMapper.get().alwaysApplyingWhenNonNull();
    map.from(provider::getAuthorizationUri).to(builder::authorizationUri);
    map.from(provider::getTokenUri).to(builder::tokenUri);
    map.from(provider::getUserInfoUri).to(builder::userInfoUri);
    map.from(provider::getUserInfoAuthenticationMethod)
        .as(AuthenticationMethod::new)
        .to(builder::userInfoAuthenticationMethod);
    map.from(provider::getJwkSetUri).to(builder::jwkSetUri);
    map.from(provider::getUserNameAttribute)
        .to(builder::userNameAttributeName);
    return builder;
}
```

So the "providerId" from `OAuth2ClientProperties.Registration` never makes it to the `ClientRegistration`, and the "providerId" from `OAuth2ClientProperties.Provider` never makes it to the `Provider` in the first place.
What you get at the end is a `ClientRegistration` with a `ProviderDetails`... but with no "providerId"...

Comment: Oh I forgot about `OAuth2ClientProperties`! I'm using it in a different context but failed to consider it in this one. I can inject it as a bean into the service where I need to do the resolution between client and provider id, and look up the provider that way. Thanks!